# Trigger Customizer Publish (save) Action

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

Is there any way to trigger the Customizer's Publish button in javascript?

The use-case is to create a secondary save button within a section.

[image: Example of Publish Button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to this. For anyone looking:

```
wp.customize.previewer.save()
```